# Flutter : build ios

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, ipa

I want to get ipa file for testing it in real iphone device
I'm using windows os but build ios in [codemagic](https://codemagic.io/) and I don't know where is the ipa file or where is the file which I should use for testing in real iphone device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you configured codemagic correctly you should see the .ipa file alongside with the other generated files under "Artifacts".

There you should be able to download them.

If you only see android files there, you probably didn't configure your codemagic correctly. Please refer to their documentation: [Codemagic Docs](https://docs.codemagic.io)

Another thing to check: Are you sure enabled iOS builds in your project settings?

Comment: yes, I was enabled ios build and the files of ios is download with name (Runner.app) file - but i can't found .ipa file in them

Comment: Did you also enable code signing like mentioned here: https://docs.codemagic.io/code-signing/ios-code-signing/

Comment: no because i haven't account on apple store

Comment: Yeah so thats the problem. You cannot run an app on iphone without signing it.